# Download html a attribute

Tags: html, imagedownload

I have link of image and I want to download it on click, I use download attribute and name of attribute but it download with default title, For example :

```
<a href="https://smartprojects.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/1855OGJI.jpg" class="download-foto ff" title="My Smart Photo" download="My Smart Photo" style="display: block;">
                Download photo              </a>
```

could you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link will help you, hold your mouse over the download button, and se which link it has 'musicsong.mp3', and when you download the file, the link renames to 'musicsong(www.xD.Bl.ee.mp3)'.
http://xd.bl.ee/baza/ - Demo
I gues use this code in a file like this page.php

```
<a href="1855OGJI.jpg" class="download-foto ff" title="My Smart Photo" download="My Smart Photo.jpg">Download</a>
```

Just try it like this, if it works modify the style...

Answer (score 0):

In case it doesn't work, then you're probably using one of the not-supported browsers.

> **Browser Support:**
>
> > Internet Explorer and Safari are not supported.
>
> Source: [HTML a download Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)